# Why 'keyup' event unable to make a change in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The mouseleave event is able to make CSS changes but when the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key is released, keyup event doesn't perform the CSS changes it's supposed to. Is it interfering with the mouseenter? if yes, then how to resolve the issue?

```js
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.el', function(e) {
  $(this).css("background-color", "white");
  $(this).css("color", "black");

});

$(document).on('keyup', '.el', function(e) {
  if (e.altKey) {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    $(this).css("color", "black");

  }
});

$(document).on('mouseenter keypress', '.el', function(e) {
  if (e.altKey) {

    $(this).css("background-color", "#99DCFC");
    $(this).css("color", "red");

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1" align="center" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email Address</th>
    <th>Telephone Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="r">
    <tbody>
      <td id="d1" class="el" contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td id="d2" class="el" contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td id="d3" class="el" contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td id="d4" class="el" contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td>
        <button id="del1">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tbody>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is working fine for me. Your code snippet is working exactly how it supposed to do. What browser are you using?

Comment: I think you'll find that `e.altKey` is `false` in the `keyup` event because the key was just released. Try changing it to `if (!e.altKey)`. But note that only an element that has focus will receive `keyup` events...

Comment: does it change the color to black and background to white when altkey released?

Comment: Yes it does @Dungeoun

Comment: @nnnnnn doing that doesn't apply the changes when the altkey is released.

Comment: @Dungeon - It does for me *if* the mouse is over the element that has focus. (Otherwise the key event belongs to the wrong element, so...)

Comment: @nnnnnn it's working just when is `ALT+ANY` I think that's the problem, `e.altKey` is used for when alt is being combined with a different key.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro try keeping the mouse on a cell while releasing the altkey, the color doesn't change.

Comment: OK, one more time: key events belong to the element with focus, not the one the mouse is over at the time. (So regardless of whether you've successfully figured out how to catch an alt key keyup event, `this` is not necessarily referring to the currently blue element.)

Comment: @nnnnnn ok... gotcha!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. In the keyup event `e.altKey` will be `false` because the alt key was just released. Try testing the actual key code instead via `e.which`.
2. Within the event handler, `this` will refer to the element that the event occurred for, which seems obvious except that that element isn't necessarily the one that the mouse is over: for a key event it will always be the element that has the (keyboard) focus at the time. The simplest fix for this is to use a class instead of setting CSS properties individually, because then you can just remove the class from whichever element currently has it by saying `$(".highlight")` rather than `$(this)`. Therefore you also you don't want a delegated event handler for `keyup`, because the focus could be on *none* of the elements in question at the time.

```js
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.el', function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass("highlight");
});

$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which === 18) {
    $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
  }
});

$(document).on('mouseenter keypress', '.el', function(e) {
  if (e.altKey) {
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #99DCFC;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t1" align="center" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email Address</th>
    <th>Telephone Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="r">
    <tbody>
      <td id="d1" class="el" contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td id="d2" class="el" contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td id="d3" class="el" contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td id="d4" class="el" contenteditable="true"></td>
      <td>
        <button id="del1">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tbody>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note also that using a class to set the colours is neater than having to repeat colour codes in separate functions.

(I think the above is still a little buggy, but it should get you much closer to where you want to be.)

Answer (score 1):

`e.altKey` actually checks whether the alt key is active after the event has been fired. Since you're setting a `keyup` event, the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key is *not* active after the event is triggered. Try changing `if (e.altKey)`  to `if (e.which === 18)`. `e.which` returns the keycode of the key that triggered the event, and 18 is the keycode for <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

Comment: I did.. but I'm not able to refer to the currently blue element. `this` does not refer to the currently blue element.